# Best Way to Backup local MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting development on a locally hosted MongoDB database (Mac).  I need to do local backups.  the database is small in size.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/),
"mongodump excludes the content of the local database in its output".

When I run Mongodump, it creates backup files, but it's unclear to me if these are sufficient given the above documentation.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: `-d local` does not do the trick?

Comment: So, would this work?:     mongodump --host mongodb.example.net --port 27017     (from a different/separate system?)